# How can I find out what password I need to use for 'su'?

Tags: command-line, osx-leopard, su

I am using Mac OS X 10.5, and have my account set up so that I don't need to login.
When I go to Network Preferences and click the lock icon on the lower left corner, I am prompted for my username and password. I simply enter my password and the lock icon becomes unlocked.

But when I go to a shell and enter `su`, I get this:

```
$ su
Password:
su: Sorry
```

What password do I enter here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `su`ing you would ned the password of the target account, `root` in this case. But on Mac OS X, root doesn't have a password, su this will never work. You can however use `sudo -i` which will give you a root shell too. You need to enter your user's password there.

Comment: `sudo -s` works as well. It mnemonics out (`sudo -s[hell]`) better for my scatterbrain processes.

Answer (score 1):

Enter `sudo su`. You can use your own password then.

Answer (score 1):

Set  a password for `root` with `passwd`:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Then you will be asked for `sudo` password, which is your usual login password,

```
Password:
```

And then you can set or change the `root` password:

```
Changing password for root.
New password:
Retype new password:
```