# LFS 8.2, cannot change user to root

Tags: linux, su

I have a problem with my Linux From Scratch 8.2 system, because when I login as normal user and then try to switch to root using su command, it prints "Authentication failure" even after entering correct password. The su command works fine the other way around (from root to normal user).

Comment: "Even after entering correct password". -- "Correct password" for root and "correct password" for user may (often should) be different. Please confirm you try the one the tool expects.

Comment: @kamilmaciorowski When you use sure it uses the users password, not the root one.

Comment: I dont use LFS, but check that your username is in the administrators group (normally wheel or adm) and that /etc/sudoers is set up to allow members if this group (or your user) to use it.

Comment: @davidgo The question doesn't mention `sudo` at all but my impression is you're drifting towards it. There's [this](https://superuser.com/q/255377/432690) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441151/108618). I still think confusing the two passwords is a plausible scenario. What am I missing?

Comment: @kamilmaciorowski you are probably right. I missed sure and thought sudo.

Comment: Great - cellphone autocorrect - sure should have said su.

Comment: I am entering the correct root password. There is no sudo, because it's clean LFS installation. And I think the wheel requirement group should be turned off by default, nevertheless I tried to create a group named wheel and add the user into it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was already able to find the solution by myself. Firstly I tried to turn root's password off and then to use su again. I got the message "setgid: Operation not permitted". Then I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/980398/unable-to-enter-superuser-using-su) and finally successfully repaired everything by command:

```
chmod 4755 /bin/su
```

I am only wondering now, why this instruction is not included in the Linux From Scratch book.